# File Download from AWS EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I want to download a file in AWS EFS using an API. If anyone knows such way of doing this please assist me.

I am currently doing a research to find a method to download the files from EFS.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EFS is an NFS network-attached disk service.

To access content on an Amazon EFS filesystem, mount it on an Amazon EC2 instance.

It is not possible to access the content of an EFS filesystem via an API.

Comment: so it means I can access EC2 instance via an API and get download the files which I want?

Comment: If you write something that will respond to those API requests, then yes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any documentation to follow? if yes that would be very helpful as I new to the industry and AWS cloud platform

Comment: Frankly, I would suggest that you re-evaluate your current system architecture. If you have content on EFS that you need accessible from an API, then EFS is probably not the place you should be storing the content.

Comment: so what is happening my system is. Upload a file to server side directory( mount path of efs) and the upload works fine. Now I need to download a file which is inside the mount path directory  to local machine using nodejs.

Comment: I do not understand your situation. Please Edit your question (at the top) to add more details. Let us know how information such as: How is the download being requested? Is it coming via a web application? What specific problem are you having when serving this file? Can't you download it in a similar way to how it was uploaded?